# Trying to make the wireworld move by fmap (transition) but it shows me an error somehow (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, dictionary

The same as my last question, im asked to make a wireworld by ordered lists, So i have written the following codes,(all of the function in the code is somehow defined in other modules, so, dont worry about that XD, feel free to ask me if u want to have a look at those "predefined funcs") however when i run it on terminal, it shows a error, here is the code:

```
module Transitions.For_Ordered_Lists_2D (
   transition_world -- :: Ordered_Lists_2D Cell -> Sparse_Line Cell
) where

import Data.Cell (Cell (Head, Tail, Conductor, Empty))
import Data.Coordinates
import Data.Ordered_Lists_2D


-- Replace this function with something more meaningful:


xandy :: Element_w_Coord Cell -> Coord
xandy (e, (x, y)) = (x, y)

transition_sc :: Ordered_Lists_2D Cell -> Placed_Elements Cell -> Sparse_Line Cell
transition_sc world pec = case world of
Sparse_Line{y_pos = y, entries =  xline}: rest_of_sparse_lines  -> case pec of
        Placed_Element{x_pos = x, entry =  Head} : rest_of_placed_elements   -> (Sparse_Line{y_pos = y, entries = Placed_Element{x_pos = x, entry =  Tail} :  rest_of_placed_elements}) 
        Placed_Element{x_pos = x, entry =  Tail} : rest_of_placed_elements   -> (Sparse_Line{y_pos = y, entries = Placed_Element{x_pos = x, entry =  Conductor} : rest_of_placed_elements}) 
        Placed_Element{x_pos = x, entry =  Empty} : rest_of_placed_elements   -> (Sparse_Line{y_pos = y, entries = Placed_Element{x_pos = x, entry =  Empty} : rest_of_placed_elements}) 
        Placed_Element{x_pos = x, entry =  Conductor} : rest_of_placed_elements
            |element_occurrence Head neighbours == 1 || element_occurrence Head neighbours == 2    -> (Sparse_Line{y_pos = y, entries = Placed_Element{x_pos = x, entry =  Head} : rest_of_placed_elements}) 
            |otherwise                                                                             -> (Sparse_Line{y_pos = y, entries = Placed_Element{x_pos = x, entry =  Conductor} : rest_of_placed_elements}) 
                where
                    neighbours = local_elements (xandy (Conductor, (x, y))) world


transition_world :: Ordered_Lists_2D Cell -> Ordered_Lists_2D Cell
transition_world world = fmap (transition_sc world) world      

--the end
--the end
--the end
```

however it shows me the following error:

```
u5363876@n114lt20:~/Desktop/lalal$ ./make_Wireworld
[10 of 20] Compiling Transitions.For_Ordered_Lists_2D ( Sources/Transitions/For_Ordered_Lists_2D.hs, x86_64/Transitions/For_Ordered_Lists_2D.o )

Sources/Transitions/For_Ordered_Lists_2D.hs:35:53:
    Couldn't match expected type `Placed_Elements Cell'
                with actual type `Sparse_Line Cell'
    Expected type: [Placed_Elements Cell]
      Actual type: Ordered_Lists_2D Cell
    In the second argument of `fmap', namely `world'
    In the expression: fmap (transition_sc world) world
```

Im totally confused by this error Thank you in advance for anyone who can help me.

@dave4420   here is the definition for Placed_Elements and Sparse_Lines

```
type Ordered_Lists_2D e = [Sparse_Line e]

data Sparse_Line e = Sparse_Line {y_pos :: Y_Coord, entries :: Placed_Elements e}

data Placed_Element  e = Placed_Element {x_pos :: X_Coord, entry :: e}
type Placed_Elements e = [Placed_Element e]
```

Comment: Show us the definitions of `Placed_Elements` and `Sparse_Line`.

Comment: Please ensure you copy+paste both your code and the error message into your question. There are details of the error message that suggest you have retyped the error message (inaccurately) instead of copying+pasting. Perhaps the code in your question is not the code you tried to compile, either. And then how can we help you?

Comment: @dave4420, i have added it into my question, check it out XD

Comment: btw, i've copy and paste the error message now, check that out as well pls XD  @dave4420

Comment: You have not shown us the definitions of `Placed_Elements` or `Sparse_Line`. You have shown us the definitions of some variables (which may, or may not, be defined in terms of something related to those types). I am asking you to show us the type definitions: they start something like `data Placed_Elements` or `type Spare_Line`. And I would like you to show us the definition of `Ordered_List_2D`. This is important because **you are asking us to solve a type error, so we need to know what the types are before we can fix it**. Or we could guess at the types and give you the wrong answer.

Comment: @dave4420, My bad XD, i've changed it this time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have very strange case

Don't use

```
case pec of
    Placed_Element{x_pos = x, entry =  Head} : rest_of_placed_elements   -> ...
```

use instead

```
case entry (head pec) of
    Head   -> ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
transition_sc :: Ordered_Lists_2D Cell -> Placed_Elements Cell -> Sparse_Line Cell
```

It expects its second argument to `[Placed_Element Cell]` -- i.e. a list of Placed_Element. But instead you're mapping it so only handing it one argument at a time instead of the whole list. And furthermore, you're calling it on a list of `Sparse_Line Cell`!

As it happens, each `Sparse_Line` has a list of `Placed_Element` inside it, so you *can* make this work. But you'll need to "reach deeper" into each element of the `Placed_Elements` to get there.

Try writing a function wrapping `transition_sc` of type `Ordered_Lists_2D Cell -> Sparse_Line Cell -> Sparse_Line Cell` and see if that helps you get further.